# delete excel rows based on column values C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba, visual-studio, vsto

i am creating excel VSTO , where I already have the macro to delete excel rows based on column values(if it is greater than zero)which now needs to be converted to c# , by seeing documentation on internet I have come up so far , but still three errors are present I am not able to solve them kindly help me:

original macro:

```
Sub delete2()
'
' delete2 Macro
'

'
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$901").AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">0", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("8:1382").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$S$891").AutoFilter Field:=10
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

modified by me till now:

```
    using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Ribbon;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core;
using Microsoft.Office.Tools.Excel;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CpCpk
{
    public partial class Ribbon1
    {
        private void Ribbon1_Load(object sender, RibbonUIEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            var excelappp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Worksheet excelApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveSheet;

            excelappp.Rows["1:1"].Select();
            excelappp.Selection.AutoFilter();
            excelappp.ActiveSheet.Range["$A$1:$S$901"].AutoFilter(Field: 10,Criteria1:">0",Operator: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd);
            excelappp.Rows["8:1382"].Select();
            excelappp.Range[excelappp.Selection, excelappp.Selection.End(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlDown)].Select();
            excelappp.Selection.delete(Shift: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlDirection.xlUp);
            excelappp.ActiveSheet.Range["$A$1:$S$891"].AutoFilter(Field:10);
            excelappp.Selection.AutoFilter();
        }
```

although there are no syntax error , I am getting below error during execution :

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'
```

kindly help me how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking to your code, I think you need to delete below line

```
var excelappp = new Excel.Application();
```

Instead use below line

```
var excelappp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
```